# ViewPager in Android - When is the destroyItem(ViewGroup container , int position) method called?

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In ViewPager i set my adapter as follows

```
myViewPagerAdapter = new MyViewPagerAdapter();
viewPager.setAdapter(myViewPagerAdapter);
```

This is my MyViewPagerAdapter class

```
public class MyViewPagerAdapter extends PagerAdapter {
private LayoutInflater layoutInflater;

public MyViewPagerAdapter() {}

@override
public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
}

@override
public int getCount() {

}

@override
public boolean isViewFromObject(View view, Object obj) {

}

@override
public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
}
}
```

What happens when i call the empty contructor in MyViewPagerAdapter? Which methods are called?

Comment: take look, PagerAdapter official doc https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/view/PagerAdapter.html#destroyItem(android.view.ViewGroup, int, java.lang.Object)

Answer (score 0):

No methods are called.

A constructor is used to create a new object of your class `MyViewPagerAdapter` and because in your case it's the default constructor (empty body) , you can skip writing it.

Ref: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9

Comment: but when are the methods of pagerAdapter called?

Comment: The ones you override are for your own use, you can call them explicitly, e.g. if you need the amount of pages loaded in the adapter: myViewPagerAdapter.getCount().

Comment: but when is instantiateItem() method called? I don't call it for my own use i,e: When does system call it?